# How to use left navigation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

My Flutter application also uses GetX
I want to refresh the target page only in the orange area on the right when clicking on the left Tab to jump to the GetX route. The left side and the header are fixed and will not be refreshed. This should be similar to a web framework, I don’t know you do you understand me
[image]
It would be great if the entire object of the target page can be obtained when the route jumps, so that the target object can be rendered to the orange area on the right, or is there any PUB plug-in that can directly solve it?

I try to get the target page Widget directly, which is no problem, but it does not use the routing management and dependency management of GetX. I hope to implement it on the basis of GetX and use GetX routing management and dependency management.

Sincere thanks for every reply！